# ¿Como sumar las columnas de una matriz con Nan y calcular su promedio?

Tags: python

Hola amigos tengo la siguiente matriz:

```
A = [[12.5,nan,23.5],
[nan,34.6,nan],
[15.4,23.5,45.1]]
```

¿Como podría calcular su promedio a cada columna sabiendo que tienen nan?

Comment: Reemplaza los nan por 0 y luego haz las operaciones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta con que recorras la columna extrayendo sólo los valores distintos a nan y calculando el promedio con ellos:

```
def prom_columna(matriz, columna):
    valores = [matriz[fila][columna] for fila in range(len(matriz)) if matriz[fila][columna] != nan]
    promedio = sum(valores) / len(valores)
    return promedio
```

Por economía se usa una *comprensión de listas*, que es equivalente a

```
valores = []
for fila in in range(len(matriz)):
    if matriz[fila][columna] != nan:
        valores.append(matriz[fila][columna])
```

#### Demo

```
A = [[12.5,nan,23.5],
[nan,34.6,nan],
[15.4,23.5,45.1]]

def prom_columna(matriz, columna):
    valores = [matriz[fila][columna] for fila in range(len(matriz)) if matriz[fila][columna] != nan]
    promedio = sum(valores) / len(valores)
    return promedio

print("Col Promedio")
for col in range(3):
    print(col, prom_columna(A, col))
```

produce

```
Col Promedio
0 13.95
1 29.05
2 34.3

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Estimado me dice que nan no está definido. Que puedo hacer?

Comment: Tienes que definir "nan". En tu pregunta no lo haces, por lo que la respuesta simplemente lo trata como una variable previamente definida. En mi caso, puse `nan = "nan"`. No se que definición aplica en tu problema.

Comment: Muchas gracias por el comentario